# WebDAV and version control

Tags: version-control, webdav

Does anyone have any insight into what, if any, provisions the WebDAV protocol makes available for version control?

In my never-ending pursuit of a good way to integrate designer tools like SharePoint Designer or Expression with a real source control (which must support live preview), I'm about resigned to the idea that I'll have to write a FPSE server (not hard, but the protocol might not be supported in future revs of the MS tools) that knows how to translate the check-in/check-out RPCs to SVN or TFS.

(I can't install IIS on the designer's machines, Cassini doesn't support classic ASP, and we need live save/preview. Apparently this is the perfect trifecta of stuff that doesn't work together).

WebDAV seems to have a potentially longer lifespan than FPSE, but I can't find a lot of information on any protocol support for check-in/check-out, only folder and file locks. Atomic commits would be nice, but I may be barking up a beanstalk with no climbing gear.

Answer (score 3):

It's all in [RFC 3253](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3253.html).

Comment: And, IIRC, subversion uses this as its wire protocol.

Comment: Not really; it never implemented the minimum to work with generic RFC 3253 clients, and always relied on custom extensions. See http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/http-and-webdav/webdav-usage.html for more details.

Comment: thanks for the link. Any idea if the MS tools support these extensions?

Comment: I'm not aware of any Microsoft products supporting this.

Comment: Thanks. Had a look at the RFC and googled a bit. It seems like this was abandoned, why? Is there at least a webdav (rfc 3253) client out there?